# Returning a Response from ArgumentValueResolver

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to avoid having all fields in my DTOs to accept a null value. How to return a value from ArgumentValueResolver ?

```
<?php
class DTOValueResolver implements ArgumentValueResolverInterface
{
public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument)
{
        // ( ... )
        try {
            $dto = $this->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), $argument->getType(), $format);
        } catch (MissingConstructorArgumentsException $exception)
        {
            // wont work - will result in 500
            throw new BadRequestException("invalid body", 0, $exception);
            // this wont work either
            return new JsonResponse(['invalid body'], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        }
        // ( ... )
}
}
```

Comment: What is the message of 500 exception when you tried to throw `BadRequestException`? Or I guess there should be critical error in log file. And also, I think, you should throw another exception `BadRequestHttpException`. It's more suitable I guess

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev Yes the BadRequestHttpException exception is thrown and client gets 500 in the status as a response but I want to return a validation error 400-422 instead of a 500 error code.

Comment: Ooooh ok I've used wrong exception... Ok I will try with BadRequestHttpException and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @UrmatZhenaliev for help.

I should have used BadRequestHttpException but instead I've used BadRequestException.

BadRequestHttpException is correctly interpreted as http 400 status code.

I've implemented my own version extending Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException and using 422 Unprocessable Entity status code.